# Complex connected subsets of a complex connected Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a connected Hausdorff space with more than a single point such that every proper non-empty non-singleton subset of the space is disconnected?

Comment: No. [A space can have at most one dispersion point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_point).

Comment: Do you mean that a connected space can have at most one dispersion point?